# Responsive cover image

Tags: html, css, responsive

I want to make a landing page for my website with a responsive background like this (http://www.montere.it/?lang=en). In that example website, the image automatically scale to the center when screen is smaller, that's something I want. Currently I have these codes but it's not working.

```css
body {
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(bg.jpg);
    background-size: 100% auto;
}

.title {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 
}
```

```html
<body>
        
        <div class="cover-wrapper">
            <div class="title">
                <h1>Angel Shih Design.</h1>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- cover-wrapper -->
</body>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a screen shot. I clicked on the link and everything seemed to work.

Answer (score 2):

With `background-size: cover;` and `absolute` position container it could work :

```
.cover-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/350/200/1);
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/cuuh4pem/2/)

Answer (score 0):

try this using viewport unit:

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height: 100%;
}

.cover-wrapper{
     display:block;
     background: transparent url(bg.jpg) no-repeat center center /cover;
     width: 100vw;
     height: 100vh;
}


.title {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/kd4kjdck/161/)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
```

Basically you want to cover all of the body with the background img, so background-size: cover should do it.

Comment: It doesnt work, when the screen gets smaller, the bg got cut off at the bottom

Comment: Sorry! Add position: absolute to the background image and it should work as wanted! And then position the image at the top with top: 0 and height: 100%. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Exactly as Vincent G said.